# Application that will move file to new folder with file's name

Tags: windows, windows-registry, context-menu, send-to

Is there any application or `.reg` file that will add new item to Windows Context menu to all files that will have this functionality:
1. create new folder with name of selected file
2. move selected file to this folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and type in *shell:sendto*
2. create a new textfile in this folder and copy & paste the following lines

   ```
   @echo off
   cd /D "%~dp1"
   md "%~n1"
   move %1 "%~dp1%~n1"
   ```
3. save it as folder.cmd (or whatever you wish as long as the extension is .cmd or .bat)

**Explanation**

- %1 » The normal parameter that represents your selected file
- cd » Change Directory - move to a specific Folder
- %~dp1 »  Extracts the drive & path from %1
- md » Make Directory - Creates a new folder
- %~n1 » Extracts the filename from %1 without the extension
- move » Move a file from one folder to another

**Source:** [batch parameters](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true) & [batch commands](http://ss64.com/nt/)

Comment: I like your improvisation :) but there is one bug. It won't move file if path contains spaces. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Oh, its fixed now.