# "sendto" all selected files into a folder

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, rename, send-to

I found this lovely time saving script which has helped me a lot.

```
@echo off
cd /D "%~dp1"
md "%~n1"
move %1 "%~dp1%~n1"
```

Script found here [Application that will move file to new folder with file's name](https://superuser.com/questions/536116/application-that-will-move-file-to-new-folder-with-files-name)

However, it will only move one file(which is what it's designed to do) into the new folder it creates, with the new folder named after the file.
I would like to select multiple files and have the batch file move them all into the new folder. Maybe use the filename of the first file to name the folder. Can someone help if this possible. Thanks, Mike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### I would like to select multiple files and have the batch file move them all into the new folder

If you are planning on using the first file to name your destination folder you can make use of `%*`:

> `%*` in a batch script refers to all the arguments (e.g. %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 ...%255)

Source: [Parameters / Arguments - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

So your script would be:

```
@echo off
cd /D "%~dp1"
md "%~n1"
for %%f in (%*) do move %%f "%~dp1%~n1"
```

This avoids the need to use `shift` as in the [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1711543/337631) by [user1686](https://superuser.com/users/1686/user1686)

Comment: Hi, thank you. This will create a new folder with the name of the last file selected (which is fine) but does not move the selected files into that folder.

Comment: @MikeS Try the update answer using a `for` loop

Comment: Yes thank you! That did it.

Answer (score 2):

After processing the first file, use [`shift`](https://ss64.com/nt/shift.html) to move the next parameter (which is currently `%2`) into the `%1` position, then [`goto`](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html) back to the beginning. (Also, don't forget to check whether [it's empty](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html#exist), to avoid looping forever.)

```
:begin
if "%~1"=="" goto :EOF
...your commands here...
shift
goto :begin
```

Alternatively:

```
:start
...your commands here...
shift
if not "%~1"=="" goto :start
```

To use a single folder name for all files, move the `mkdir` command out of the loop (i.e. place it *above* the `:begin` label), and save the path in [a variable](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) so that it could be referenced even after the initial `%1` gets shifted away:

```
set "target=%~dpn1"
mkdir "%target%"
```

Now the loop can move all files to `"%target%"`.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks so very much. Works a treat.

Comment: Ahh, I spoke to soon. If I select multiple files, run the script, it will now create a folder for each of the selected files, instead of putting all the selected files into the one, newly created folder.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much but it didn't work. It moved the last selected file into the new folder but removed the file extensions from the other selected files and left them where they were.  The answer below from @DavidPostill has done the trick

Answer (score 0):

[TeraCopy for Windows](https://www.codesector.com/teracopy) has a built in feature that allows you to do it even faster.

If you select multiple files > right click > click on **New folder with selection** > which will create a folder named '*New Folder With Items*' and move your selected files into it.

[image]

For this to work, you have to enable '**Add to explorer context menu**'

[image]